# mod_rewrite works fine on linux but returns forbidden on windows 10

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wampserver

I'm working with wampserver on windows 10 for local development.
after that i made my script live and it works fine but after some days i implemented url rewrite.
my scipts works fine on live server.
now i want to do some changes so i made it local for development and i'm getting **Forbidden** on my local host.

here is rewrite rules

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([-\w]+)/(\d+)/([-\w]+)$ $1.php?cat_name=$2&vid=$3&vbiz_name=$4 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([-\w]+)/(\d+)$ $1.php?cat_name=$2&page=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([-\w]+)$ $1.php?cat_name=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [NC,L]

# Error Documents
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error/500.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/500/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 500.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is Virtual Host details i'm using.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName devproject
    DocumentRoot "g:/dev-project"
    <Directory  "g:/dev-project/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

index page works fine...
Please help me out..

Comment: What is the request that delivers the "Forbidden" reply and what does your http server's log files say about that request?

Comment: FYI: RewriteConds only apply to the immediately following RewriteRule. So only your first rule here has the restriction that it should not apply, when the requested URL matches an existing file or folder. But if you made a request that matches the pattern of the second rule, `^(.*)/([-\w]+)/(\d+)$`(or the next ones), that request would be rewritten, even if there was a matching file or folder. (Could be what one wants, in certain situations, but usually it is not.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved...
I just added a new line

```
Options FollowSymLinks
```

just after

```
RewriteEngine on
```

And it works on windows as well as on Linux both,
New Rules looks like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([-\w]+)/(\d+)/([-\w]+)$ $1.php?cat_name=$2&vid=$3&vbiz_name=$4 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([-\w]+)/(\d+)$ $1.php?cat_name=$2&page=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([-\w]+)$ $1.php?cat_name=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [NC,L]

# Error Documents
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error/500.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/500/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 500.php [L]
</IfModule>
```